# Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, native

how can i solve this problem?

```
PS C:\Users\dys07\nomad tutorial\fokin-weather> npm install mem
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})    

+ mem@6.0.1
removed 1 package, updated 1 package and audited 71136 packages in 6.08s

8 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 4 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
PS C:\Users\dys07\nomad tutorial\fokin-weather> npm audit

                       === npm audit security report ===                        


                                 Manual Review                                  
             Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve             

          Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance           


  Low             Denial of Service                                             

  Package         mem                                                           

  Patched in      >=4.0.0                                                       

  Dependency of   6adb22a9faae706d217a717535ec3be4afebe5e7d62a588f7807fafdba1…  

  Path            6adb22a9faae706d217a717535ec3be4afebe5e7d62a588f7807fafdba1…  
                  > @react-native-community/cli > metro >                       
                  metro-inspector-proxy > yargs > os-locale > mem               

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1084                             


  Low             Denial of Service                                             

  Package         mem                                                           

  Patched in      >=4.0.0                                                       

  Dependency of   6adb22a9faae706d217a717535ec3be4afebe5e7d62a588f7807fafdba1…  

  Path            6adb22a9faae706d217a717535ec3be4afebe5e7d62a588f7807fafdba1…  
                  > @react-native-community/cli > metro-config > metro >        
                  metro-inspector-proxy > yargs > os-locale > mem               

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1084                             


  Low             Denial of Service                                             

  Package         mem                                                           

  Patched in      >=4.0.0                                                       

  Dependency of   6adb22a9faae706d217a717535ec3be4afebe5e7d62a588f7807fafdba1…  

  Path            6adb22a9faae706d217a717535ec3be4afebe5e7d62a588f7807fafdba1…  
                  > @react-native-community/cli > metro > yargs > os-locale >   
                  mem                                                           

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1084                             


  Low             Denial of Service                                             

  Package         mem                                                           

  Patched in      >=4.0.0                                                       

  Dependency of   6adb22a9faae706d217a717535ec3be4afebe5e7d62a588f7807fafdba1…  

  Path            6adb22a9faae706d217a717535ec3be4afebe5e7d62a588f7807fafdba1…  
                  > @react-native-community/cli > metro-config > metro > yargs  
                  > os-locale > mem                                             

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1084                             

found 4 low severity vulnerabilities in 71136 scanned packages
  4 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can

> run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details